# Certificate and Private Key from server not in bundle for AWS IOT connection in swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am receiving certificate and private key from server to connect with AWS iot. Is there any method that takes certificate and private key as parameters and returns as .p12 file in aws SDK?

Or is there any other way to create .p12 file with received certificate and private key in swift 2.3?

Or if it is any other way, please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/issues/133) which has details about preparing the .p12 file for use with the iOS sample application.  Let us know if that information helps, and thanks for using AWS IoT.